# Hide all header contents in Org mode

Tags: org-mode, outline-mode, outline

`outline-show-all` reveals the contents of all headers in `org-mode`. How can I do the opposite? There's no `outline-hide-all` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need `(hide-sublevels 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

This function is obsolete since 25.1;
use ‘outline-hide-sublevels’ instead.